# Tags for specific books

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it would be helpful if tags for specific electronics books could be created. People learning electronics often study from books and if they're having trouble, say with a specific circuit from a particular book, it would be helpful to subsequent users if the book tag could be used to narrow down search results to questions for that specific book. For example, if I'm having a problem with a circuit that occurs in the book "Make: Electronics" I get some search results that match, but many others that don't match because the words "make" and "electronics" are pretty generic.

Comment: You know there are much books out there? We would get way too much tags, all with one or two questions.

Comment: @CamilStaps There are questions on SE:EE with lists of electronics books. I think there are only 20 or so that are  popular. We would only need to create tags for those questions that are asked. If it helps users navigate the site does it matter how many there are?

Comment: ThomasW Can you list all the books you would like to create tags for? As @CamilStaps I think there's too many too handle, but I like your idea.

Comment: The tag system was never designed to be this granular.

Answer (score 6):

This makes no sense as it would by definition fall under *too localized*.  Books come and go, the popularity of those books come and go, and the popularity varies widely by region.

If someone has a question about something they see in a book, they should distill it down to a paragraph or so, probably with a quote from the relevant passage or scan of the schematic.  Put the title and author name of the book in the question, and anyone that happens to bump into that same issue should be able to find the question well enough.